ARM Trusted Firmware - Label or Path not found inside the .dts file
Purpose
I'm trying to compile ARM Trusted Firmware (TF-A) in STM32MP by using STM32CubeIDE.
Requriments

Linux e.g *buntu Linux distro 22.04 and above
Eclipse IDE
STM32MP SDK

Problem
When I compile the TF-A, I'm getting that the labels such as fmc, i2c, sdmmc, spi etc cannot be found. The path is missing is missing inside the .dts files.
23:03:35 **** Build of configuration Default for project stm32-computer-pin-configuration_CA7_tf-a-2.8.15-r2 ****
make -f ../Makefile.sdk.ide TF_A_DEVICETREE=stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx TF_A_CONFIG=optee-sdcard stm32 metadata 
Wrapper for /opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.16.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mpu.linux.toolchain_2.1.0.202305092038/tools/bin/make
FIP_DEPLOYDIR_ROOT: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../../FIP_artifacts
+ case "$command" in
+ exec make -f ../Makefile.sdk.ide TF_A_DEVICETREE=stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx TF_A_CONFIG=optee-sdcard stm32 metadata
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2'
Including bl32/optee/optee.mk
Trusted Firmware-A built for OP-TEE payload support
PSA_FWU_SUPPORT is an experimental feature
  CPP     /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.dts
  DTC     /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.dts
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:946.18-29 Label or path fmc_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:947.18-30 Label or path i2c2_pins_a not found
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2'
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:948.18-30 Label or path i2c4_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:950.18-34 Label or path qspi_bk1_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:951.18-34 Label or path qspi_bk2_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:952.18-34 Label or path qspi_clk_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:953.18-35 Label or path sdmmc1_b4_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:954.18-36 Label or path sdmmc1_dir_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:955.18-36 Label or path sdmmc1_dir_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:956.18-35 Label or path sdmmc2_b4_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:957.18-35 Label or path sdmmc2_b4_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:958.18-36 Label or path sdmmc2_d47_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:959.18-36 Label or path sdmmc2_d47_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:960.18-36 Label or path sdmmc2_d47_pins_c not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:961.18-36 Label or path sdmmc2_d47_pins_d not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:963.18-31 Label or path uart4_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:964.18-31 Label or path uart4_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:965.18-31 Label or path uart7_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:966.18-31 Label or path uart7_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:967.18-31 Label or path uart7_pins_c not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:968.18-31 Label or path uart8_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:969.18-32 Label or path usart2_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:970.18-32 Label or path usart2_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:971.18-32 Label or path usart2_pins_c not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:972.18-32 Label or path usart3_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:973.18-32 Label or path usart3_pins_b not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:974.18-32 Label or path usart3_pins_c not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:975.18-41 Label or path usbotg_fs_dp_dm_pins_a not found
Error: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.pre.dts:976.18-35 Label or path usbotg_hs_pins_a not found
FATAL ERROR: Syntax error parsing input tree
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1453: /home/lubuntu/Dokument/GitHub/stm32-computer/STM32CubeIDE/stm32-computer-pin-configuration/CA7/tf-a-2.8.15-r2/tf-a-stm32mp-v2.8.15-stm32mp-r2/../build/optee-sdcard-stm32mp15-stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx/fdts/stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx-bl2.dtb] Error 1
make: *** [../Makefile.sdk:232: tf-optee-sdcard-stm32mp15] Error 1
"make -f ../Makefile.sdk.ide TF_A_DEVICETREE=stm32mp151a-stm32-computer-pin-configuration-mx TF_A_CONFIG=optee-sdcard stm32 metadata" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

23:03:37 Build Failed. 31 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.745ms)

Reproduce
This is the steps how to reproduce this issue.
Step 1:
Begin to download the STM32CubeIDE here: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html
Select your Linux version, DEB, RPM or Generic.
Step 2:
Begin to download the SDK here: https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32mp1dev.html
Choose your artitechture: ARM, x86, x86-Rust (Yes, ST supporting Rust now)
For the x86 case:
Extract
tar xvf en.sdk-x86_64-stm32mp1-openstlinux-6.1-yocto-mickledore-mpu-v24.06.26.tar.gz

If that won't work:
gzip -d en.sdk-x86_64-stm32mp1-openstlinux-6.1-yocto-mickledore-mpu-v24.06.26.tar.gz
tar xvf en.sdk-x86_64-stm32mp1-openstlinux-6.1-yocto-mickledore-mpu-v24.06.26.tar

If needed:
chmod +x stm32mp1-openstlinux-6.1-yocto-mickledore-mpu-v24.06.26/sdk/st-image-weston-openstlinux-weston-stm32mp1-x86_64-toolchain-4.2.4-openstlinux-6.1-yocto-mickledore-mpu-v24.06.26.sh

Just install the SDK in a folder. Press enter.
Step 3:
When you have installed the following:

STM32CubeIDE
STM32MP SDK

Then it's time to create a project. Open up STM32CubeIDE. Don't forget to login to My ST account. Select a new project as the picture below shows.

Step 4:
Select your processor. There are the choices:

STM32MP15XXXX
STM32MP13XXXX

I selected STM32MP151AAC3. Press next.

Give it a name:

It's very important that you have logged into your ST account when you're pressing finish. Then it will download the firmware, compiler and all other tools.

Step 5:
Once you have created your project, it's time to set up the SDK inside the STM32CubeIDE. Just right click on CA7 folder and select Setup OpenSTLinux.

Press Yes

Select the installation folder of the SDK and press Apply and Close.

Step 6:
It's time to add ARM Trusted Firmware.
Right click on CA7 and select Import an OpenSTLinux Project...

Here you can select:

Linux kernel
Optee-OS
TF-A (ARM Trusted Firmware)
U-boot

Select tf-a and press finish.

Step 7:
Generate the .dts files for your project. The .dts files are Device Tree files.

Step 8:
Now it's time to reproduce the error. Just right click and press Build target. Now you will get the same error as I have above.

Your compiled files will now be inside this folder:

Walk around & Question:
There is a walk around for this.
If you open the file stm32mp15-bl2.dtsi inside the fdts folder inside tf-a folder at your STM32MP project. If you remove these /omit-if-not-ref/ &<pefierial>, the error will not appear when you are building your project.

The problem is that...this is not a good option to an answer. Sure, this will work, but it's not meant to be like this. So something is wrong and missing and I don't know why. Also, I have some issues with the .stm32 file inside the FIP folder. It's probably that I have removed the /omit-if-not-ref/ &<pefierial>.
